# How to make a column of a table editable?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I'm trying to make a table that will allow a user to enter a mark out of 10 given some criteria. I'm connected to my SQLite database and retrieving a column on the left for the description of the criteria, and a column on the right where I want to be able to enter a grade (an editable column). Here is my code:

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel();

QSqlQuery* qry = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);

qry->prepare("select I.itemDescription, S.grade from Items I, ItemsToStudent S where     I.itemID = S.itemID and I.rubricID = ? and S.courseID = ? and S.studentID = ?");
qry->addBindValue(actid);
qry->addBindValue(courseid);
qry->addBindValue(studentid);
qry->exec();
model->setQuery(*qry);
ui->rubricTable->setModel(model);
```

However, I can't make the second column editable. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `QSqlQueryModel` class provides a read-only data model for SQL result sets. You can use `QSqlRelationalTableModel` like:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel *model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this,conn.mydb);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
model->setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel::LeftJoin);
model->setTable( "Items" );
model->setRelation( 0, QSqlRelation( "ItemsToStudent", "itemID", "grade" ) );

model->setFilter( QString("rubricID = ? and courseID = ? and studentID = ?") );
model->select();

model->setHeaderData( 1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Criteria") );
model->setHeaderData( 2, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Grade") );

ui->rubricTable->setModel(model);
```

You can also hide the columns you don't want to show like:

```
ui->rubricTable_tbl->hideColumn(3);
```

Comment: There are some fields I do not wish to be able to edit, like the criteria column. How do I make a specific column non-editable? 
Also when I try to enter a grade in the grade column it returns a blank, and the value I entered isn't updated in the database. Should I use a signal to update or is the relational table model supposed to do that automatically?

Comment: Alright I found out my first question through some googling. Will try to look for number 2.

Comment: you can have a custom model and implement the Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags ( const QModelIndex & index ) const method and return a set of flags where the Qt::ItemIsEditable flag is not set for the cells you do not want to edit.

Comment: For the second problem I'm getting a QSqlQuery::exec: database not open error.

Comment: Do you call the open() of conn.mydb?

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming that is how I'm populating the table. What happens is when I try to edit a row I get that error, and afterwards I can't edit any other rows.

Comment: Update: I got rid of the error (I was closing the connection as soon as I finished populating the table), but I still can't update the data  I input.